# No such module PDKClient with Cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I have installed the Pinterest SDK with cocoapods successfully, but when I try to import PDKClient, it says "No such module PDKClient".

My podfile:

```
target 'MyPin3' do
pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyPin3

end
```

I definitely have my xcworkspace open and I have tried clean + build. I've looked up some other Stack Overflow answers (tried deleting framework search paths, etc.) with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `PDKClient`, you should be importing `PinterestSDK`. Try this line and it should work:

```
import PinterestSDK
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got confused by the documentation. It's working fine now!

Comment: Happy to help and I'm glad that you were able to get it working :)